# HtmlPurifier - disable special chars replacement

Tags: config, htmlpurifier

I have been looking in the doc(config part) and in google, I cant find how to do this:

I make a simple wysiwig where users can paste html in a text area

I thought HtmlPurifier would sanitize it, but it actually destroys eveything
rendering the html unusable, accents are also replaced which is not user friendly for editions

is it possible to disable the replacement of accents by &...;
same for the html, I want it to remain valid

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();

$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$data=$purifier->purify($data);
```

thanks

[edit]

found this :

```
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'enduser-customize.html tutorial');
$config->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 1);
$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null); // remove this later!
$def = $config->getHTMLDefinition(true);
$def->addAttribute('a', 'target', new HTMLPurifier_AttrDef_Enum(
  array('_blank','_self','_target','_top')
));
$form = $def->addElement(
  'form',   // name
  'Block',  // content set
  'Flow', // allowed children
  'Common', // attribute collection
  array( // attributes
    'action*' => 'URI',
    'method' => 'Enum#get|post',
    'name' => 'ID'
  )
);
$form->excludes = array('form' => true);
```

- how to enable all tags, I am not going to do this by hand this makes no sens
- what do I do with $form variable ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found out, angular sanityzer was removing everything

please delete this question

thanks